# Transforming SQL to Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
items (id, name, description, subcategory_id, sublocation_id)
categories (id, name)
subcategories (id, name, category_id)
locations (id, name)
sublocations (id, name, location_id)
```

I am trying to implement a search feature for a laravel 5.4 application. I am taking the following user inputs in order to run a search: 1) The search string  2) Category ID 3) Location ID.

However, these three inputs reside in 3 different tables. So in conventional SQL, to get all the items having category_id = 1 and location_id = 1, I would have written a statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE name LIKE 'A%' AND subcategory_id IN (SELECT id FROM sub_categories WHERE category_id = '1') AND sublocation_id IN (SELECT id FROM sub_locations WHERE location_id = '1')
```

**Models:**

**SubCategory.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SubCategory extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'name', 'category_id',
    ];

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

**Category.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'name',
    ];

    public function subcategories(){
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class);
    }
}
```

**Location.php** & **Sublocation.php** models are pretty much the same as these two so I didn't post them here.

How can I use hasManyThrough() relationship in both Category and Location models to get all the $items? Or is there any other simple way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to constrain by relationships.

Assuming you have the following relations on `Item`

```
    class Item extends Model
    {
        public function subcategories()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(SubCategory::class);
        }

        public function sublocation()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(SubLocation::class);
        }
    }
```

Then you can do:

```
Item::where('name', 'LIKE', 'A%')
    ->whereHas('subcategories', function($query) use ($categoryId) {
        return $query->where('category_id', $categoryId);
    })
    ->whereHas('sublocation', function($query) use ($locationId) {
        return $query->where('location_id', $locationId);
    })
    ->get();
```

To take this one step further you could also implement [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes) on your `Item` class such as:

```
    class Item extends Model
    {
        //Item Class

        public function scopeWhereCategory($query, $categoryId)
        {
            return $query->whereHas('subcategories', function($query) use ($categoryId) {
                return $query->where('category_id', $categoryId);
            });
        }

        public function scopeWhereSublocation($query, $locationId)
        {
            return $query->whereHas('sublocation', function($query) use ($locationId) {
                return $query->where('location_id', $locationId);
            });
        }
    }
```

Then your query would be:

```
Item::where('name', 'LIKE', 'A%')
    ->whereCategory($categoryId)
    ->whereSublocation($locationId)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Undefined variable: categoryId

Comment: Ok my apologies, I forgot to pass in the values in whereCategory and whereSublocation methods

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to use Algolia to implement the search feature: 
https://www.algolia.com

Here are some tutorials for larvel 5.4:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6McM360FIw

Algolia will give you tons of options to filter and will make super efficient queries :).

If you try this and have any doubts, let me know.

Comment: Laravel has a search functionality that integrates with Algolia as well. It's called [Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scout).

Answer (score 1):

You can build the same query the following way:

```
$subCategories = SubCategory::where('category_id', 1)->select('id');
$subLocations  = SubLocation::where('location_id', 1)->select('id');
$items = Item::where('name', 'like', 'A%')
    ->whereIn('subcategory_id', $subCategories)
    ->whereIn('sublocation_id', $subLocations);
```

That can also be written in one expression:

```
$items = Item::where('name', 'like', 'A%')
    ->whereIn('subcategory_id', SubCategory::where('category_id', 1)->select('id'))
    ->whereIn('sublocation_id', SubLocation::where('location_id', 1)->select('id'));
```

This is not the most efficient way, but pretty simple.

In plain SQL I would use JOINs instead of IN conditions:

```
select i.*
from items i
join subcategories sc on sc.id = i.subcategory_id
join sublocations  sl on sl.id = i.sublocation_id
where i.name like 'A%'
  and sc.category_id = 1
  and sl.location_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but which do you think would be the most efficient way to handle situations like this? I am new to Laravel, as you may have already guessed.

Comment: @Eisenheim - In plain SQL I would write a JOIN query.